# Runtime Configuration for Angular 6+ Applications

Tags: javascript, angular, deployment, angular-cli, web-deployment

What is the recommended best practice for loading environment specific configuration during runtime of an Angular application?  The Angular documentation mentions the use of APP_INITIALIZER, but that is still not early enough in the load process for things such as runtime configuration of imported modules that make use of the .forRoot() convention.

In my use case, I have an authentication service built and imported via a Core module, which is imported by the App module.  The authentication library I am using (the [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) library) allows for configuration of the automatic appending of access tokens during when importing the module (see [this segment](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc#calling-a-web-api-with-an-access-token)).  Since there are constraints in the build environment I am working with that only allows me to produce one common build package to deploy to all environments, I am unable to dynamically set values by using different environment.ts files.

One initial idea is to use the fetch API on the index.html page to load a JSON file containing the configuration onto a global variable, but since the call is asynchronous, there is a chance the configuration will not be fully loaded when the import of the Core module occurs.

Answer (score 3):

This was part of my config setup to bring my app through the build pipeline and took me days. I ended up in a solution using the `APP_INITIALIZER` loading a REST service and build a `AppConfigService` for my App. I am using the same [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc) library.

My Solution for this issue was not to setup the OAuthModule in its forRoot() method. It is called before any configs via `APP_INITIALIZER` are available - this results in undefined values when applied to the config object given to the `forRoot()` Method.

But we need a token in the http header. So I used a http interceptor for the attaching of the token like described [here](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/additional-documentation/working-with-httpinterceptors.html). The trick is to setup the  OAuthModuleConfig in the factory. Obviously this is called after the app is initialized.

**Configure Module**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // no config here
    OAuthModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [
   {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useFactory: authenticationInterceptorFactory,
    deps: [OAuthStorage, AuthenticationErrorHandler, OAuthModuleConfig],
    multi: true
   }
 ]
})
```

**Factory for interceptor**

```
const authenticationInterceptorFactory = (oAuthService: OAuthStorage, authenticationErrorHandler: AuthenticationErrorHandler, oAuthModuleConfig: OAuthModuleConfig) => {
const config = {
 resourceServer: {
  allowedUrls: [
   // Include config settings here instead
   AppConfigService.settings.apiURL,
   AppConfigService.settings.anotherApiURL,
  ]
  sendAccessToken: true
 },
}
return new AuthenticationInterceptor(oAuthService, authenticationErrorHandler, config);
};
```

Comment: In this case, are you using your own custom HttpInterceptor?  I was exploring ways to leverage the built in DefaultOAuthInterceptor from the library, which was why I was initially trying to find ways to initialize the needed values to pass as the configuration object in the forRoot method.

Comment: I use an the HttpInterceptor linked in my above and changed some details (mostly rxjs6). It seems not possible to configure the needed values in the `forRoot()` Method because it is called before the `APP_INITIALIZER`.

Comment: @vaci you literally saved my day (or week). I couldn´t get OAuthModuleConfig value in a provider because providers dont work async, and there´s was no way of setting it in APP_INITIALIZER either. I was always close, but ended up with Promises instead of actual values... So your trick of creating a new interceptor and just ignoring OAuthModuleConfig was just perfect. Simple and elegant. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a library [angular-runtime-config](https://github.com/vdolek/angular-runtime-config#readme) for runtime configuration loading for Angular.

**Simple usage example**

Your custom `Configuration` class:

```
export class Configuration {
  readonly apiUrl!: string; // only example
  readonly apiKey?: string; // only example
  // add some other configuration parameters
}
```

Registering [angular-runtime-config](https://github.com/vdolek/angular-runtime-config#readme) module with declaring which configuration files to load. For example, you can determine it by application URL or you can even use Angular injector in the factory or make the factory asynchronous.

```
import { AngularRuntimeConfigModule } from 'angular-runtime-config';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    AngularRuntimeConfigModule.forRoot(Configuration, {
      urlFactory: () => [ 'config/config.common.json', 'config/config.DEV.json' ]
    })
  ],
}
```

Then request your `Configuration` class in any injection context.

```
@Injectable({...})
export class SomeService {
  constructor(private readonly config: Configuration) {}
}
```