# How to load different authentication modules in angular based on runtime configuration

Tags: angular, module

How to load different types of authentication modules based on the environment using a runtime configuration (I'm able to load config during runtime using `APP_INITIALIZER`).

EDIT:

sample code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dwod6w?

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941908/runtime-configuration-for-angular-6-applications

Comment: @aniskhalfaoui i added a sample code

Comment: @TomaszKula can u help? i saw u answered a similar question. thanks